# PHP hash_hmac(sha512) to Python new hmac()

Tags: python, php, hash, hmac

php code

```
    function get_signature($data, $secret_key) {
        $algo = "sha512";
        $result = hash_hmac(
            $algo,
            $data,
            $secret_key,
            false
        );

        return $result;
}
```

python code (Tried)

```
def get_signature(data, secret_key):
    signature = hmac.new(secret_key.encode(), data.encode(), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
    print(signature)

    return signature
```

the hashed value is not same.
how can I get same value as in php code from python code?

thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. Please make a [mre], complete with key, data, and output.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks a lot. I solved problem. The problem was in json that passed to data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code is working properly.
the issue was on another code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).